# Regular expression to parse timestamp

Tags: php, regex

Timestamp is in this format `date('m-d-Y H:i:s A')` which will result `08-26-2011 16:00:25 PM`.

I need a regular expression to parse a file with time stamps starting with last week and last month, ignore previous time stamps. Basically something like this:

```
if(preg_match("/TimestampsWithinLastWeek+String/", $match))
{
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is not the right tool for this, use `strtotime()` instead:

```
if( strtotime( $dateString ) > strtotime( "Monday last week" ) ) {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use either [`date_parse`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) or [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) instead of regular expressions... the overhead will be much less.

Comment: How can i use `date_parse` to check the date that's within last week?

Comment: You've just gotta do the math. Dates and times boil down to UNIX timestamps, so you can subtract the two dates and do a bit of math to figure out if the time span is greater than one week. This is definitely not something that you should be doing with Regex though, that's more of a glorified "Find and replace" engine than a date/time thing.